# iTextSharp PDF To Text Header and Footer Read Issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, itext

I am try Convert PDF(.pdf) to Text(.txt) Using iTextSharp Library,But in Text File Extra space add between words,

---

- Content In PDF

**"Location Path: D:\PDF Files\Projects\101-14-A\2015_10_12\Test Methods\121015.pdf"**

- Content In Text File after converting pdf to txt file

**"L ocation Path**: D:\PDF Files\Projects\101-14-A\2015_10_12\Test Methods\121015.pdf"

- Some time i will get below Content In Text File

"Location Path: D:\PDF Files\**Projects \101-14-A \**2015_10_12\Test Methods\121015.pdf"

I am Using below Code for Convert PDf To Text File

```
Imports iTextSharp

Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

Dim sOut As String = String.Empty

Dim oReader As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(Filepath)

Dim strategy1 As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy

Dim strategy2 As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.LocationTextExtractionStrategy


sOut &= iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(oReader, 1, strategy1)

sOut &= iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(oReader, 1, strategy2)

End Sub
```

---

In Both Strategy Result is unexpected So,Please Kindy Replay Any Other

Comment: Please share the PDF in question. Extra spaces may be due to either a bit spaced out writing or to actually existing (but overprinted) space characters

Comment: Hello Sir,I also Share All pdf in Your mail Id Kindly check

Comment: I'll take a look at that later (most likely on Monday).

Comment: At first glance: In "Method Path" the two letters 'M' and 'e' do not properly follow each other, they actually nearly overlap! iText in such a case wants to indicate that the letters are not properly following each other, and as a String does not contain a small back-step, iText expresses this by means of a space character. I'll later explain how to soften iText's idea of letters "properly following" one another.

Answer (score 0):

## At first glance

I checked the files the OP provided using the current iTextSharp version 5.5.7. First of all, *they do not show the exact problem the OP describes* because none of the documents even contains a *Location Path* line. They do show a comparable behavior, though, for footers like this:

[image: Method Path: D:\Analyst Data\Projects\879...]

Here extracting with the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` indeed returns

```
M ethod Path: D:\Analyst Data\Projects\879...
Results Path: D:\Analyst Data\Projects\879...
```

I already explained some backgrounds for this in a comment:

*In "Method Path" the two letters 'M' and 'e' do not properly follow each other, they actually nearly overlap! iText in such a case wants to indicate that the letters are not properly following each other, and as a String does not contain a small back-step, iText expresses this by means of a space character.*

But the situation here differs from the situation the OP described because extraction using the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` returns:

```
Method Path: D:\Analyst Data\Projects\879...
Results Path: D:\Analyst Data\Projects\879...
```

Thus, I would propose that the OP checks the version of iTextSharp he uses and switches to the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` of the current library version.

If even after updating to the current version the issue remains, please share the PDF with which the problem can be observed with the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`, too.

## At second glance

As the OP insisted that there were spaces where none should be, even in the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` output, I indeed found some after searching again and again (a hint concerning the whereabouts of the spaces would have been nice...)

I found "A nalyst", "O perator", and "W orkstation" in the header section.

The reason for them, unfortunately, has nothing to do with iText pointing at text chunks not properly following each other. Instead the reason is that there **is** a space character. E.g. in case of "A nalyst" the content stream looks like this:

```
q
1.0 1.0 1.0 rg
29.28 822.24 39.12 4.8 re
f
BT
/F2 4.515 Tf
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg
0.9998 0.0 0.0 1.0 29.28 823.2 Tm
[( )] TJ
ET
Q
q
BT
/F2 4.515 Tf
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg
0.9998 0.0 0.0 1.0 29.28 823.2 Tm
[(A)30(n)21(a)18(l)65(y)21(s)-36(t)12( )-15(V)137(e)71(r)14(s)-36(i)65(o)-31(n)21(:)65( )-15(1)21(.)-15(6)21(.)-15(2)] TJ
ET
Q
```

I.e. after drawing a white rectangle (**re**, **f**), a space character is drawn (**[( )] TJ**) at exactly the same position (**0.9998 0.0 0.0 1.0 *29.28 823.2* Tm**) as the 'A' of analyst (**[(A)...] TJ**).

After sorting the text chunks, the space happens to appear right after the 'A' (the order of characters at the same position after sorting is arbitrary), so you get the "A nalyst".

One might consider changing the text extraction strategy to keep the original order of characters printed in the same location, but that after all might break other documents. Still...

## A more faithful extraction strategy

We will attempt to tweak the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` to keep the order of text chunks which are anchored at the same position.

The `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` explicitly is arbitrary in this regard:

```
virtual public int CompareTo(TextChunk rhs) {
    if (this == rhs) return 0; // not really needed, but just in case
    
    int rslt;
    rslt = CompareInts(orientationMagnitude, rhs.orientationMagnitude);
    if (rslt != 0) return rslt;

    rslt = CompareInts(distPerpendicular, rhs.distPerpendicular);
    if (rslt != 0) return rslt;

    // note: it's never safe to check floating point numbers for equality, and if two chunks
    // are truly right on top of each other, which one comes first or second just doesn't matter
    // so we arbitrarily choose this way.
    rslt = distParallelStart < rhs.distParallelStart ? -1 : 1;

    return rslt;
}
```

*(`LocationTextExtractionStrategy.TextChunk`)*

This arbitrary choice not only is unnecessary, it also violates the contract coupled with the `IComparable` interface which this method implements:

> For objects A, B and C, the following must be true:
>
> `A.CompareTo(A)` must return zero.
>
> If `A.CompareTo(B)` returns zero, then `B.CompareTo(A)` must return zero.
>
> If `A.CompareTo(B)` returns zero and `B.CompareTo(C)` returns zero, then `A.CompareTo(C)` must return zero.
>
> **If `A.CompareTo(B)` returns a value other than zero, then `B.CompareTo(A)` must return a value of the opposite sign.**
>
> If `A.CompareTo(B)` returns a value `x` not equal to zero, and `B.CompareTo(C)` returns a value `y` of the same sign as `x`, then `A.CompareTo(C)` must return a value of the same sign as `x` and `y`.
>
> *([MSDN on IComparable.CompareTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.icomparable.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx))*

Especially the bolded condition is not met.

The following text extraction strategy is not arbitrary here but keeps the order in which text chunks arrive as final comparison element.

```
class FaithfulLocationTextExtractionStrategy : LocationTextExtractionStrategy
{
    public class FaithfulTextChunk : TextChunk
    {
        public FaithfulTextChunk(String stringValue, Vector startLocation, Vector endLocation, float charSpaceWidth, int index)
            : base(stringValue, startLocation, endLocation, charSpaceWidth)
        {
            this.index = index;
            orientationMagnitudeField = typeof(TextChunk).GetField("orientationMagnitude", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
            distPerpendicularField = typeof(TextChunk).GetField("distPerpendicular", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
            distParallelStartField = typeof(TextChunk).GetField("distParallelStart", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        }

        override public int CompareTo(TextChunk rhs)
        {
            if (this == rhs) return 0; // not really needed, but just in case

            if (rhs is FaithfulTextChunk)
            {
                int rslt;
                rslt = CompareInts((int)orientationMagnitudeField.GetValue(this), (int)orientationMagnitudeField.GetValue(rhs));
                if (rslt != 0) return rslt;

                rslt = CompareInts((int)distPerpendicularField.GetValue(this), (int)distPerpendicularField.GetValue(rhs));
                if (rslt != 0) return rslt;

                rslt = CompareFloats((float)distParallelStartField.GetValue(this), (float)distParallelStartField.GetValue(rhs));
                if (rslt != 0) return rslt;

                return CompareInts(index, ((FaithfulTextChunk)rhs).index);
            }
            else
                return base.CompareTo(rhs);
        }

        private static int CompareInts(int int1, int int2)
        {
            return int1 == int2 ? 0 : int1 < int2 ? -1 : 1;
        }

        private static int CompareFloats(float float1, float float2)
        {
            return float1 == float2 ? 0 : float1 < float2 ? -1 : 1;
        }

        int index;
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo orientationMagnitudeField, distPerpendicularField, distParallelStartField;
    }

    public override void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        LineSegment segment = renderInfo.GetBaseline();
        if (renderInfo.GetRise() != 0){ // remove the rise from the baseline - we do this because the text from a super/subscript render operations should probably be considered as part of the baseline of the text the super/sub is relative to 
            Matrix riseOffsetTransform = new Matrix(0, -renderInfo.GetRise());
            segment = segment.TransformBy(riseOffsetTransform);
        }
        TextChunk location = new FaithfulTextChunk(renderInfo.GetText(), segment.GetStartPoint(), segment.GetEndPoint(), renderInfo.GetSingleSpaceWidth(), nextIndex++);
        getLocationalResult().Add(location);        
    }

    public FaithfulLocationTextExtractionStrategy()
    {
        locationalResultField = typeof(LocationTextExtractionStrategy).GetField("locationalResult", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    }

    List<TextChunk> getLocationalResult()
    {
        return (List<TextChunk>) locationalResultField.GetValue(this);
    }

    System.Reflection.FieldInfo locationalResultField;
    int nextIndex = 0;
}
```

Using this strategy I extract " Analyst" instead of "A nalyst", " Operator" instead of "O perator", and " Workstation" instead of "W orkstation".

As numerous used variables are private, the class uses reflection. This might not be allowed in some contexts. In such contexts, therefore, simply work these changes into a copy of the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` code.

Comment: Hello Sir,Thank You ,for Reply. I also Check and Test Same PDF With New Version 5.5.7. of iTextSharp but same problem was found, So thats way once again I attach PDF Files and Text Files with Both strategy. So that you can check exact senario

Comment: It would have been way easier if you simply had pointed out a sample word to look for! I searched the file again and again and only now found something, "A nalyst", "O perator", and "W orkstation" in the second file. I'll be looking into that. BTW, the files you sent were of no help, somehow text file contents do not match what their file names suggest.

Comment: I explained about those three words with blanks in them. Are there more in the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` output?

Comment: hello Sir, as you say implement new FaithfulLocationTextExtractionStrategy Class. But I don't get expected result insted result is more inproper  Me Code is                                                                    Dim strategy2 As New clsFaithfulLocationTextExtractionStrategy   and                                              sOut &= iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(oReader, 1, strategy2)

Comment: *more inproper* - please exemplify.

Comment: Hello Sir, I also attach generated text file in your mail. Thank you.

Comment: I'm currently on a smart phone which does not understand rar archives, so I could not look at the file. I do hope the problem is immediately obvious or you have alternatively pointed it out. I do not want to have to search.